# Error while using Z3 module in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, z3

I am new to OCaml. I installed Z3 module as mentioned in this [link](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~sc40/COMP507/Assignments/assign1.pdf)

I am calling Z3 using the command:

```
ocamlc -custom -o ml_example.byte -I ~/Downloads/z3-unstable/build/api/ml -cclib "-L ~/Downloads/z3-unstable/build/ -lz3" nums.cma z3ml.cma  $1
```

where $1 is replaced with file name.

```
type loc = int

type var = string

type exp =
 | Mul of int * exp
 | Add of exp * exp
 | Sub of exp * exp
 | Const of int
 | Var of var

 type formula =
  | Eq of exp * exp
  | Geq of exp
  | Gt  of exp

 type stmt =
  | Assign  of var * exp
  | Assume  of formula

  type transition = loc * stmt * loc

module OrdVar =
struct
  type t = var
  let compare = Pervasives.compare
end
module VarSets = Set.Make( OrdVar )

type vars = VarSets.t

module OrdTrans =
struct
  type t = transition
  let compare = Pervasives.compare
end
module TransitionSets = Set.Make( OrdTrans )

type transitionSet = TransitionSets.t

type program = vars * loc * transitionSet * loc

let ex1 () : program = 
    let vset = VarSets.empty in
    let vset = VarSets.add "x" vset in
    let vset = VarSets.add "y" vset in
    let vset = VarSets.add "z" vset in
    let ts = TransitionSets.empty in
    (* 0  X' = X + 1 *)
    let stmt1 = Assign( "x", Add( Var("x"), Const(1) ) ) in
    let tr1 = (0,stmt1,1) in
    let ts = TransitionSets.add tr1 ts in
    (vset,0,ts,10)
```

In the above code I am defining some types. Now if I include the command "open Z3", I am getting "Error: Unbound module Set.Make".

I could run test code which uses Z3 module with out any difficulty, but unable to run with the above code.

Comment: where do you put the `open Z3`? Can you actually provide the code that doesn't compile

Comment: I tried putting "open Z3" at the top of the code and also at the end of the code which i posted above. I didn't even start using z3 commands, but still getting syntax error

Comment: That does not make sense.  If you were getting `Unbound module Z3` that would be understandable but there is no preprocessing of your file that could generate syntactically incorrect code.

Comment: @ChriS Sorry for the mistake in the question. It is saying "Error: Unbound module Set.Make", when i include z3 libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The error message in this case is a little bit confusing. The problem is that Z3 also provides a module called `Set`, which doesn't have a `make` function. This can be overcome simply by not importing everything from Z3, as there are a number of modulse that might clash with others. For example,

```
open Z3.Expr
open Z3.Boolean
```

will work fine and opens only the `Z3.Expr` and `Z3.Boolean` modules, but not the `Z3.Set` module. so that we can write an example function:

```
let myfun (ctx:Z3.context) (args:expr list) = 
  mk_and ctx args
```

If `Z3.Boolean` is not opened, we would have to write `Z3.Boolean.mk_and` instead, and similarly we can still access Z3's `Set` module functions by prefixing them with `Z3.Set.`